# Copy-Items: Copying the same folder more than once

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I try to copy the files and folder that is last access 1 year ago and this is my script:

```cs
$Source = "\\UNC\Path\Folder\"
$Dest = "\\UNC\Path2\Folder\1"

$Get = Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse | where {
    $_.LastAccessTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMonths(-12).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
} 
$Get | Copy-Item -Destination $Dest -Recurse
```

The script works except it copies the files and folder more than once.

For example, it will copy `\\UNC\Path\Folder\a\b\File1.txt` to both:

- `\\UNC\Path2\Folder\1\a\b\File1.txt`
- `\\UNC\Path2\Folder\a\b\File1.txt`

Note it skips the folder called `1` and puts it directly under `Folder`.

Now the `File1.txt` have been copied twice and it's the same file, just different dest. location.

I have Googled and search this forum but I haven't found anything. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: I think `get-childitem` will find `\folder1, \folder1\a` then `Copy-Item` will try to copy `folder1` including everything inside it, and then try to copy `folder1\a` - which has already been copied. I guess you do't need `-recurse` on both, or you need more complicated code, but I would look to use RoboCopy for this, it has `/MAXLAD` and `/MINLAD` parameters to choose things by Last Access Date (LAD).

Comment: I tried without -Recurse on Copy-Items but then I got something else that wasn't correct (can't remember what it was).
But I did it with Robocopy and it worked great (as always :) ). I missed that Robocopy had /MAXLAD and /MINLAD.

Answer (score 1):

I used RoboCopy as @TessellatingHeckler suggested and it work great!

```
Robocopy.exe \\Source\folder\Folder1 \\dest\folder\folder\1 /MAXLAD:365 /e /copyall /log:C:\Logs\log.txt
```

Robocopy source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx#Copy_all_content_including_empty_directory

> /maxlad:  Specifies the maximum last access date (excludes files
>   unused since N).
>
> /minlad:  Specifies the minimum last access date (excludes files
>   used since N) If N is less than 1900, N specifies the number of days.
>   Otherwise, N specifies a date in the format YYYYMMDD